# Cleaning up photos for personal objects

Tags: modeling, import, image

Newbie question. I would like to add personal items like diplomas or painting, where I need to capture info from my own photos. I'm just coming over to Blender from using Sketchup to model my apartment, and had problems with this for a couple reasons.

One, the photo does not produce a rectangular image of a rectangular physical object. I'm guessing there are free image processing tools, or add-ons that can be used to correct this. Is it recommended to do this inside or outside of Blender, and please recommend a free program or add-on for this. This is just a retirement hobby.

Two, the image is from a framed object with a glass cover and so contains reflections from when and where it was taken. How do I remove these effects so Blender can add back in new ones later from whatever lighting and directions are appropriate? And while I'm asking, is it better to model the underlying surface and add a glass object above, or just model the top of the glass, and teach it about the underlying subsurface by combining nodes somehow?

Comment: Hello :). These are all pretty good questions, but please separate them into three different posts. It will increase your chances for relevant answers :).

Comment: Hello and welcome Please ask only one question per post, make as many as necessary. Also have in mind that your last question "*is it better to model the underlying surface and add a glass object above, or just model the top of the glass*" is subjective and will likely generate opinion based answers which are not a good fit for this site. These are best asked in sites like https://blenderartists.org

Comment: To address your question you can use any of the open source image editing software outhere, like [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org), or [Krita](https://krita.org/en/krita-4-3-release-notes) or any of the simpler ones like paint.net or similar